# NSight Debugging very slow on any memory allocation

Tags: cuda, nsight

I am trying to debug a kernel that uses some surface objects and cuda arrays. To that end I am using NVIDIA NSight with my VS2017, debugging in Next-Gen mode. However, it takes forever (waited 10 minutes, then cancelled the run) to run over `cudaMallocArray` invocations that are necessary calls before my kernel launches. Is there any way around it?

The following minimal code that actually does nothing but allocate said arrays, takes forever to execute with NSight debugging.

main.cpp:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

int main() {
  int width = 800;
  int height = 600;

  // Allocate CUDA arrays in device memory
  cudaChannelFormatDesc colorDescription = cudaCreateChannelDesc(8, 8, 8, 8, cudaChannelFormatKindUnsigned);
  cudaChannelFormatDesc depthDescription = cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 0, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
  cudaArray *colorArray;
  cudaMallocArray(&colorArray, &colorDescription, width, height, cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore);
  cudaArray *depthArray;
  cudaMallocArray(&depthArray, &depthDescription, width, height, cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore);

   return 0;
}
```

**Update:**

I managed to replace surfaces with plain `cudaMalloc` -- same result.

---

Specification details:

- System: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit (v. 1803, build 17134.829)
- GPU: GeForce GTX 780 (plain, no 'Ti' or anything)
- GPU Driver 430.86
- CUDA v. 10.1.168
- Nsight v. 2019.2.0.19109

---

**Edit2:**

Upon further investigation, I halted the execution of my simple program (with `cudaMalloc` instead of arrays) and the call stack shows this:

```
ntdll.dll!00007ffc9b69b1e4() Unknown
kernel32.dll!00007ffc9aecb093() Unknown
kernel32.dll!00007ffc9af096f5() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc4037a38c() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc4037a532() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc40379dae() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc40377b05() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc40374515() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc405cd13b() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc40442807() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc4054bb84() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc4055abed() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc4055aee6() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc4055a022() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc4054b163() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc4040b4c7() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc4040ea85() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc4030588c() Unknown
nvcuda.dll!00007ffc4049a3e8() Unknown
NSightSlow.exe!cudart::contextStateManager::initPrimaryContext(struct cudart::device *) C++
NSightSlow.exe!cudart::contextStateManager::tryInitPrimaryContext(struct cudart::device *) C++
NSightSlow.exe!cudart::contextStateManager::initDriverContext(void) C++
NSightSlow.exe!cudart::contextStateManager::getRuntimeContextState(class cudart::contextState * *,bool) C++
NSightSlow.exe!cudart::doLazyInitContextState(void) C++
NSightSlow.exe!cudart::cudaApiMalloc(void * *,unsigned __int64) C++
NSightSlow.exe!cudaMalloc() C++
> NSightSlow.exe!main() Line 10 C++
NSightSlow.exe!invoke_main() Line 79 C++
NSightSlow.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() Line 288 C++
NSightSlow.exe!__scrt_common_main() Line 331 C++
NSightSlow.exe!mainCRTStartup() Line 17 C++
kernel32.dll!00007ffc9aec4034() Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007ffc9b6d3691() Unknown
```

It seems it is related to the (lazy) context creation on the first CUDA function call. It may not be related to `cudaMalloc` specifically.

Comment: one suggestion would be to file a bug at developer.nvidia.com.  using the word forever is also not a very clear way to define the issue.  I understand it is long. You might indicate whether it ever proceeded, how long that took, or if it never proceeded, how long you waited before giving up.

Comment: Please provide NVIDIA driver version, Nsight VSE version, CUDA Toolkit version, OS version, and GPU info. I ran basic test on my configuration and it increased execution time when debugging from 2 secs to 5-8 secs. If you can provide the additional information I can communicate it to the development team. I would still recommend filing a bug as suggested by Robert.

Comment: Updated the post. I had problems finding the bug reporting section, but I believe I have found it now.

Answer (score 1):

I got feedback from NVidia employer that Next-Gen is not supported on Kepler architecture, like mine GTX 780. There should be an appropriate error message, but there was none.

There is a detailed list on what is supported where:

https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-supported-gpus-full-list#SupportedComputeConfigs